# Is there a TSLint Rule to check for single equals?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-typings, tslint

In my code I got a bunch of bugs lately due to typing things like `if(a = b)`.

This may sound silly, but I really do need a rule to get rid of this.
especially when I type `array.find(val => val.id = 0)`.

I know that there is a rule to enforce boolean expressions in simple statements like if and for and so on... 
But is there also a rule which enforces the same in like funtions?

Comment: idk why the downvote, this is a mistake juniors in my team make occasionally that produces hard to detect bugs. Would be handy to have.

Comment: Yes exactly... I usually don't make these mistakes but especially if you are tired something like this can also happen to a professional...

Answer (score 0):

you can add `"triple-equals": true` in your `tslint.json` file to enforce the triple equals.

Comment: Yes but this doesn't detect single equals